# Explicit examples of Milnor join $*$ construction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

Could someone help me to verify the claim that the Milnor join $*$ construction https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Milnor+construction to define the topological space from a finite group will give the following results?

> 1) $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  =S^1$$
>
> 2)  $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  * \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}  =S^2$$

Here the finite group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ of order 2 and $S^n$ is a $n$-sphere.

Do I have the correct intuition / answers above? **How do we show my guesses rigorously step-by-step?** Start from the very basic to the claim above.

Comment: Yes, because the group has $2$ elements, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234065/are-there-familiar-expressions-for-finite-joins-of-finite-groups).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this further?

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, so you mean mine 1) and 2) are correct indeed?

Comment: @wonderich : That ncatlab page is wrong, and I have submitted a report to its authors through its discussion page.  Milnor's 1956 article defines a coarser topology on the set-theoretic join and uses the notation $\circ$ instead of $\ast$.  It follows by the tube lemma that both topologies $X \circ Y$ and $X \ast Y$ are equal if $X$ and $Y$ are **compact** Hausdorff spaces, such as your examples.  For a noncompact example, the geometric-topologist's cone $\mathbb{R} \circ pt$ is strictly coarser than the algebraic-topologist's cone $\mathbb{R} \ast pt$.

Answer (score 2):

To understand $E_n \mathbb Z/2$ as a space, note that $\mathbb Z/2 \cong S^0$.
The space $S^0 * X$ is also called the [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) of $X$, denoted by $SX$ and should be visualized as two cones on $X$ (in the link you can see the suspension of $S^1$.)
It is fairly easy to convince yourself that $SS^n \cong S^{n+1}$, and this can be proved using stereographic projection.
Therefore, the $n$-th step in Milnor's construction is $E_n \mathbb Z/2=S^{n+1}$, and thus the colimit is $E \mathbb Z/2=S^\infty$.
(Sanity check: [the infinite sphere is indeed contractible](http://should%20be%20visualized%20as%20two%20cones%20on%20$X$), as $EG$ should be)

To understand the action, remember that if $X$ is a $G$-space, then the induced action on $G*X = I\times G\times X/(0,a,y)\sim(0,b,y),(1,a,y)\sim(1,a,z)$ is given by $g.[t,h,x]=[t,gh,gx]$.
In the case where $G=\mathbb Z/2$ this means that the action of $1$ acts on the $X$ part separately and switches from one cone to the other.
It follows by simple induction that the action of $1$ on $E_n \mathbb Z/2=S^{n+1}$ is the antipodal map, $x \mapsto -x$, and therefore the same is true for the colimit $E \mathbb Z/2=S^\infty$.
(Sanity check: the antipodal map is continous and has no fixed points, thus the $\mathbb Z/2$ action is indeed continous and free)

Since $0$ acts on $E \mathbb Z/2$ trivially, we conclude that
$$B \mathbb Z/2 \cong (E \mathbb Z/2)/(\mathbb Z/2) \cong S^\infty/x \sim -x \cong {\mathbb RP}^\infty$$
i.e. the [infinite real projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Infinite_real_projective_space).